# Strange behavior characters afer submit in IE (it doen't happen in FF)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm extending an existing code based on Struts2 (and Struts2-jquery plugin, but I don't think this is the reason of the problem).

I found a strange behavior with Internet Explorer 9 (I don't know if the same issue exists also for the previous versions of IE) that doesn't appear in FireFox.

I've a page with some input fields and an upload function used to upload files on the server. When the user upload a file, this is sent to the server by a form submit, then the Action return to the same page (reload the page). If I fill the input boxes using accented letters, when the page is reloaded after the form submit, instead of the accented letters appears a "square" (it is `&#65533;`). This happens only in IE, not in FireFox (where the characters remain the same I've before the submit).

In the `web.xml` and `struts.xml` files, there are not encoding configuration for the JSP.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<s:form id="actionForm" name="actionForm"
    theme="simple" cssClass="yform"
    action="changeAction" acceptcharset="UTF-8">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>field1</td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield id="field1" name="field1" maxlength="2048" value="%{field1}" disabled="false" size="98" required="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><s:file name="docFacFileUploaded" size="50" /></td>
            <td>
                <sj:submit targets="main_section" id="uploadFileButton" value="File upload" button="true" indicator="indLoad" />
                <img id="indLoad" src="indicator.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display:none" />
            </td>
        <tr>
        </tr>
            <td>field2</td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield id="field2" name="field2" maxlength="2048" value="%{field2}" disabled="false" size="98" required="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <sj:submit targets="main_section" id="salvaButton" value="Salva" button="true" indicator="ind" />
                <img id="ind" src="indicator.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display:none" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the OTN Forum at URL https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3151892

As suggested, I've added this in the `web.xml`

```
<jsp-config>  
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>utf-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group> 
</jsp-config>
```

And this to my JSP page

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
```

So it rightly worked in IE and FF.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using a different character encoding than the one your browser is set to. UTF-8 unicode has some differences from ISO-8859-1, for example. Foriegn sites are even worse. Usually the browser can auto detect it, but it doesn't always seem to work.

Go to the view **menu>character encoding** and try out the options there until you find one that displays correctly.

```
<%page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I've tried to put <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> but it not worked for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preserve the same `character set` across the whole chain of operations in your Web Application, from sending the request from client and receiving the request from server, to sending the response from server and receiving the response from client.

With `UTF-8` encoding in web.xml you will be ok for every step except the request reception by the server for `GET` methods (you will need to configure your Application Server connectors to use `UTF-8` for them);

Note that your database should be `UTF-8` too, and not (as I've seen in many case in Italy) `WE81ISO8859P1` nor `P15`...

UTF-8 has everything you need, just use it **everywhere**, and you will be ok.

As an important note, remember to always specify the charset when

- creating new `Strings` from `Byte Arrays`

  instead of `new String(myByteArray);`

  use `new String(myByteArray,"UTF-8");`
- and when obtaining `Byte Arrays` from `Strings`:

  instead of `myString.getBytes();`

  use `myString.getBytes("UTF-8");`